# How to use reduce() to convert multidimensional array to key value pairs?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, reduce

I have a multidimensional array that I would like to rearrange to a key:value pair.

This is the code I have already:

```
var userSavedScenario = [["Nigeria",1,"Solar"],["Ghana",20,"Wind"]]

var mongoForm = userSavedScenario.reduce(function(acc,scenario) {
var mongoDBForm = {
  'country':scenario[0],
  'capacity':scenario[1],
  'fuel':scenario[2]
  }

  acc[scenario] = mongoDBForm
  return acc
  },{})
```

The output of this is:

```
{Ghana,20,Wind={country=Ghana, fuel=Wind, capacity=20.0}, Nigeria,1,Solar={country=Nigeria, fuel=Solar, capacity=1.0}}
```

How do I get the result to only be:

```
{country=Ghana, fuel=Wind, capacity=20.0},{country=Nigeria, 
fuel=Solar, capacity=1.0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you use `Array.map` instead of `Array.reduce`.

For example:

```js
var userSavedScenario = [["Nigeria",1,"Solar"],["Ghana",20,"Wind"]];

var result = userSavedScenario.map(function(row){
        return {
            "country":row[0],
            "capacity":row[1],
            "fuel":row[2]
        };
    });

console.log(result);
```